# PHP array group by value & min-max

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need help with merging array in PHP, I have this array, I'm trying group items by **model** and merge min and max value from **year**:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSF 1250 Bandit
        [year] => 2006
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSF 1250 Bandit
        [year] => 2007
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSF 1250 Bandit
        [year] => 2008
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSX 1250FA
        [year] => 2011
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSX 1250FA
        [year] => 2012
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSR 600
        [year] => 2006
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSR 600
        [year] => 2007
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSR 600
        [year] => 2008
    )
```

I would like group items by **model** and merge min and max value from **year**, like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSF 1250 Bandit
        [year] => 2006 - 2008
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSX 1250FA
        [year] => 2011 - 2012
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [brand] => SUZUKI
        [model] => GSR 600
        [year] => 2006 -2008
    )
```

I know how to group items by model, but I cannot achieve merge years:

```
foreach($array as $row){
    $newArray[$row["model"]] = array(
        "brand" => $row["brand"],
        "model" => $row["model"],
        "year" => $row["year"]
    );
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Suggestion: group data and record all the years first. Then you can either map or walk the array and transform the array of years into the string you wish it to be.

Comment: `$newArray["year"][] => $row["year"]; ` and after the loop  change to min(arr)-max(arr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This splits it into 2 stages, first gather the data with a min and max years for each item.  When setting the min and max's, it checks the previous value (or defaults it if not found) and applies the appropriate `min()` or `max()`...

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $row){
    $newArray[$row["model"]] = array(
        "brand" => $row["brand"],
        "model" => $row["model"],
        "minyear" => min($newArray[$row["model"]]["minyear"] ?? PHP_INT_MAX, $row["year"]),
        "maxyear" => max($newArray[$row["model"]]["maxyear"] ?? PHP_INT_MIN, $row["year"]),
    );
}
```

This generates...

```
Array
(
    [GSF 1250 Bandit] => Array
        (
            [brand] => SUZUKI
            [model] => GSF 1250 Bandit
            [minyear] => 2006
            [maxyear] => 2008
        )

    [GSX 1250FA] => Array
        (
            [brand] => SUZUKI
            [model] => GSX 1250FA
            [minyear] => 2011
            [maxyear] => 2012
        )

)
```

You can then process this to provide the year in the format you are after ( removing the no longer used fields)...

```
foreach ( $newArray as &$row )  {
    $row['year'] = $row['minyear'] . " - ". $row['maxyear'];
    unset ( $row['minyear'], $row['maxyear'] );
}
```

which produces...

```
Array
(
    [GSF 1250 Bandit] => Array
        (
            [brand] => SUZUKI
            [model] => GSF 1250 Bandit
            [year] => 2006 - 2008
        )

    [GSX 1250FA] => Array
        (
            [brand] => SUZUKI
            [model] => GSX 1250FA
            [year] => 2011 - 2012
        )

)
```